# keep spaces when printing using printf

Tags: json, bash, jq

This is how my input looks like:

```
pollresp={
    "ImportImageTasks": [
        {
            "Description": "SP",
            "ImportTaskId": "import-ami-123456",
            "Status": "deleted",
            "StatusMessage": "User initiated task cancelation"
        }
    ]
}
```

Using jq, I am filtering the object based on ImportTaskId and printing Status and StatusMessage.

This is how my filter expression looks like:

```
printf "%s\n%s\n%s" $(echo ${pollresp} |  jq '.ImportImageTasks[] | select(.ImportTaskId=="import-ami-123456") | .ImportTaskId,.Status,.StatusMessage')
```

Output comes as:

```
"import-ami-123456"
"deleted"
"Userinitiated
task
cancelation"
```

StatusMessage has spaces. I am trying to preserve the spaces and get the output as:

```
"import-ami-123456"
"deleted"
"User initiated task cancelation"
```

How do I do it?

Comment: You need quotes around your command substitution `"$(echo ...)"` otherwise it will be split on whitespace.

Comment: If you want to prepend literal text, why not do that in your `jq` code?

Comment: Why are you using `printf` at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bash by default splits arguments on spaces, so the output of your echo is being split on spaces.

```
jq '.ImportImageTasks[] | select(.ImportTaskId=="import-ami-123456") | .ImportTaskId,.Status,.StatusMessage' <<< "$pollresp"
```

Will output:

```
"import-ami-123456"
"deleted"
"User initiated task cancelation"
```

Comment: You're still missing some quotes here, such that data is getting string-split and glob-expanded on its way into `jq` (though at least you fixed the string-splitting and glob expansion on the way out). Needs to be `echo "$pollresp"` -- or better, just run `jq ... <<<"$pollresp"`

Comment: ...to see that have a real effect, try a `pollresp` value containing a whitespace-surrounded asterisk -- say, inside one of the description strings; the code given in this answer would replace it with a list of filenames in the current directory.

Answer (score 2):

Written for clarity and readability, this might look like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

jq_script='
.ImportImageTasks[]
| select(.ImportTaskId=="import-ami-123456")
| [.ImportTaskId, .Status, .StatusMessage]
| @tsv
'

while IFS=$'\t' read -r importTaskId status statusMessage; do
  printf '%s\n' "$importTaskId" "$status" "$statusMessage"
done < <(jq -r "$jq_script" <<<"$pollresp")
```

Note the `@tsv` on the end of the `jq` pipeline -- that generates tab-separated output, which the `while IFS=$'\t' read -r var1 var2 var3` loop -- as described in [BashFAQ #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) -- iterates over.

<sub>*(If doing this in a security-sensitive context, I would suggest amending your `jq` expressions to strip tabs and newlines from content fields -- or, if those are legitimate data, [switching to NUL delimiters](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/issues/1271) and stripping those).*</sub>

Answer (score 1):

The issue is not with `jq`, it's with the way you're using the bash subshell.  Here is a script that demonstrates the difference.

```
#!/bin/bash
pollresp='{
    "ImportImageTasks": [
        {
            "Description": "SP",
            "ImportTaskId": "import-ami-123456",
            "Status": "deleted",
            "StatusMessage": "User initiated task cancelation"
        }
    ]
}'

filter='
    .ImportImageTasks[] 
  | select(.ImportTaskId=="import-ami-123456") 
  | .ImportTaskId,.Status,.StatusMessage
'


echo _________________________ with printf "%s\n%s\n%s" unquoted subshell
printf "%s\n%s\n%s" $(echo ${pollresp} | jq "$filter")

echo
echo _________________________ with printf "%s\n" quoted subshell
printf "%s\n" "$(echo ${pollresp} | jq "$filter")"

echo _________________________ with no subshell
jq "$filter" <<< "$pollresp"

echo _________________________ with while/read
while read -r ImportTaskId
      read -r Status
      read -r StatusMessage
do
    printf "%s\n%s\n%s\n" "$ImportTaskId" "$Status" "$StatusMessage"
done < <(jq "$filter" <<< "$pollresp")
echo _________________________
```

Here is the output demonstrating the difference.  I would recommend the while/read approach if you want to further format or process the result from jq in bash.

```
_________________________ with printf %s\n%s\n%s unquoted subshell
"import-ami-123456"
"deleted"
"Userinitiated
task
cancelation"
_________________________ with printf %s\n quoted subshell
"import-ami-123456"
"deleted"
"User initiated task cancelation"
_________________________ with no subshell
"import-ami-123456"
"deleted"
"User initiated task cancelation"
_________________________ with while/read
"import-ami-123456"
"deleted"
"User initiated task cancelation"
_________________________
```

Comment: The "with quoted subshell echo" is still a bit wrong -- it's quoting the subshell, but not the parameter expansion with the original JSON data. That may not make a difference with *this specific* data, but there definitely exists valid JSON which it would corrupt and/or leak data (ie. attacker-chosen filenames, if an attacker can generate arbitrary status-message text) into.

Comment: You're correct my description of that case is poor.  I wouldn't advise that approach in any event.

Answer (score 0):

Just correct your approach to the following:

```
echo "$pollresp" | jq '.ImportImageTasks[] | select(.ImportTaskId=="import-ami-123456") | .ImportTaskId,.Status,.StatusMessage'
```

The output:

```
"import-ami-123456"
"deleted"
"User initiated task cancelation"
```

Comment: I should have mentioned that I want to append some literal text before each line. That is the reason i was using printf

Comment: @Asdfg, you did not show *some literal text* in your expected output. Anyway, you should enclose your `$pollresp` variable in double quotes